# Can we have an anonymous struct as template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, struct, anonymous-types

The title is pretty self-explanatory, but here's a simplified example:

```
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T>
struct MyTemplate {

    T member;

    void printMemberSize() {
        printf("%i\n", sizeof(T));
    }

};

int main() {

    MyTemplate<struct { int a; int b; }> t; // <-- compiler doesn't like this

    t.printMemberSize();

    return 0;

}
```

The compiler complains when I try to use an anonymous struct as a template argument.  What's the best way to achieve something like this without having to have a separate, named struct definition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not allowed to *define* an unnamed type as a template argument in C++03 or even in C++0x.

The best you can do it to create a named struct local to main (in C++0x<sup>1</sup>)

<sub>1 :  You are not allowed to use a local type as template argument in C++03, however C++0x allows it.</sub>

Also check out the Defect Report [here](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#62). The proposed solution mentions

> The following types shall not be used as a template-argument for a template type-parameter:
>
> - a type whose name has no linkage
> - **an unnamed class or enumeration type that has no name for linkage purposes (7.1.3 [dcl.typedef])**
> - a cv-qualified version of one of the types in this list
> - a type created by application of declarator operators to one of the types in this list
> - a function type that uses one of the types in this list

---

> The compiler complains when I try to use an anonymous struct as a template parameter.

Did you mean template argument? Template parameter is different from template argument.

For example

```
template < typename T > // T is template parameter
class demo {};

int main()
{
   demo <int> x; // int is template argument
}
```

Comment: In C++0x, an object of an unnamed type can be deduced as a template argument, but I don't think an unnamed type can be specified explicitly in the template argument list.

Comment: Prasoon, can you refer me to the right section of the standard please?  My test case with an unnamed struct (passed to a typedef, but we all know that a typedef name is not a struct name) compiles just fine.

Comment: @Prasoon: Thanks.  Looks like that restriction definitely is removed in C++0x.  Still can't define a type inside the template argument list though, which is the question actually posed by the code (as opposed to the title).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying argument vs. parameter - I guess I had always just used the terms interchangeably, but yes, I meant argument.  I tried using a locally defined, named struct for the template *argument* but the results were the same.  (I am using GCC 4.5's C++0x support.)

Comment: Nevermind - evidently this won't work on MinGW 4.5, but it does work on GCC 4.5.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem isn't that the struct is unnamed, it's that the struct is declared locally.  Using local types as template arguments is not permitted in C++03.  It will be in C++0x though, so you might try upgrading your compiler.

EDIT: Actually, your problem is that inside a template argument list isn't a legal place to put a class definition, with or without a name, according to the C++ standard.

litb points out that although it fits into the C++0x grammar, defining a type here is forbidden by `[dcl.type]`:

> A type-speciﬁer-seq shall not deﬁne a class or enumeration unless it appears in the type-id of an alias-declaration (7.1.3) that is not the declaration of a template-declaration.

```
simple-template-id:
    template-name < template-argument-list_opt >

template-argument-list:
    template-argument ..._opt
    template-argument-list , template-argument ..._opt

template-argument:
    constant-expression
    type-id
    id-expression

type-id:
    type-speciﬁer-seq abstract-declarator_opt

type-speciﬁer-seq:
    type-speciﬁer attribute-speciﬁer-seq_opt
    type-speciﬁer type-speciﬁer-seq

type-speciﬁer:
    trailing-type-speciﬁer
    class-speciﬁer
    enum-speciﬁer

class-speciﬁer:
    class-head { member-speciﬁcation_opt }
```

For a while I had a question about typedef names, but litb cleared that up.  They are allowed as template arguments via:

```
trailing-type-speciﬁer:
    simple-type-speciﬁer
    elaborated-type-speciﬁer
    typename-speciﬁer
    cv-qualiﬁer

simple-type-speciﬁer:
    :: opt nested-name-speciﬁer_opt type-name
    :: opt nested-name-speciﬁer template simple-template-id
    char
    char16_t
    char32_t
    wchar_t
    bool
    short
    int
    long
    signed
    unsigned
    float
    double
    void
    auto
    decltype-speciﬁer

type-name:
    class-name
    enum-name
    typedef-name
    simple-template-id
```

Comment: Actually I'm using GCC 4.5's C++0x capabilities.  Is this feature not be implemented there yet?

Comment: @nonoitall: The [C++0x tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b0x/info) has links to lots of information on the status of C++0x support in several compilers.  It says it's supposed to be added in gcc 4.5.  The [official gcc release notes](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html) say "In C++0x mode local and anonymous classes are now allowed as template arguments".  You are compiling with the `-std=gnu++0x` option, right?

Comment: My bad.  Evidently this is something that got left behind on the MinGW port of GCC 4.5.  Tried compiling it on a Linux box and it will compile when using a locally defined struct (though using an anonymous struct as an argument still won't fly).  /me goes to install Cygwin.

Comment: The "... it shall not appear in the type-id." is just meant to say that "using foo = foo;" is forbidden. It talks about such alias declarations. When resolution for http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1044 is applied, then that text can be removed.

Comment: @Johannes: Thanks!  and also "Hey the bat signal worked!"  What's your assessment of actually defining a type inside a template argument list?

Comment: @Ben 7.1.6/3 last sentence of n3225.

Comment: @Ben I can't actually find where C++03 forbids it. In fact, it seems that GCC doesn't know either, since it actually compiles the following code: `template<typename> struct A { }; A< struct B { } >::SomeNonSense int y;`.

Comment: @Johannes: I guess I made the mistake of never trying that at namespace scope... so C++03 compilers correctly rejected a reference to a local class, and C++0x correctly rejected a definition placed there.

Comment: @Johannes: I can't parse that line of code either... is there supposed to be a semicolon before `int y;`?

Comment: @Ben it's just complete nonsense. GCC should have rejected already when we tried to define the type. It makes no sense at all, that's why GCC internally goes all mad.

Comment: @Johannes: Oh good... I would hate to start the new year having lost my mind ;)